# Web Site Development & Site Support Tender -

Tags: bids

I came across this tender notice for Web Site Development and Site Support in The Daily Express dated December 13, 2010. I was wondering why interested web developers have to pay so much money (US$300) just to submit a bid? (why should we have to pay anything at all, coming to think of it). Is it to attract serious bidders only, or to make money[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its commonplace in the US but it sounds very dodgy to me.

Comment: +1 Me too. Its like applying for a job, and your boss says to you you need to purchase a computer to do your new job.

Answer (score 1):

It seems weird on the surface, and I'd be concerned it was a scam, but when you consider the cost of preparing a tender in terms of time (salaries) the $300 isn't that much on top of it.

The argument would be that you pay $300 with no guarantee of wining the tender, but in reality you invest far more in preparing it with the same guarantee.

I wouldn't want to pay it, seems a bit odd, and makes me think scam.  In order to determine if a bidder is serious or not, I have generally seen a pre-tender response required which allows the client to determine if you're up to the task.  Based on these pre-tender responses, they then send the real request for tender with actual requirements out to the short list to complete.  Saves everyone a lot of time.

Comment: +1 Judging from the responses so far, it seems uncommon to charge bidders a non refundable fee. It seems unethical to me, or just plain greedy.